# Multi-Value Assignment Behavior in Scala

Tags: java, scala

When Scala evaluates the following multiple value assignment:

```
val a, b, c = UUID.randomUUID()
```

I expected `a == b && b == c && c == a` (**A**) or `a == null && b == null && c == UUID` **(B)**

However, the result is `a != b && b != c && c != a` (**C**), where each value is initialized to an individual UUID.

Why is this? Java behaves like **(B)**. I believe that **(C)** is more convenient, however I have not been able to find an explanation in the language doc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [scala language reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) section 4.1:

> A value definition `val p1, ..., pn = e` is a shorthand for the sequence
>   of value definitions `val p1 = e; ...; val pn = e`.

So your example is shorthand for:

```
val a = UUID.randomUUID()
val b = UUID.randomUUID()
val c = UUID.randomUUID()
```

Comment: Great Answer. Thanks for including the link to the language reference, too!